# Missing Java plug ins with U.S. Patent office web site

Tags: firefox, java, firefox-extensions

I am trying to utilize the U.S. patent web site and I am unable to view the publication images as the site states that I need to download a missing plug-in for Firefox.  When I select the Missing Plug-in button I receive "No suitable Plug-ins Found".

I made sure that I have the most recent version of Java from the Ubuntu Software Center, restarted my browser, but yet have not been able to get this to work.  The link I am trying is [here](http://aiw2.uspto.gov/.aiw?Docid=20080065488&homeurl=http://appft1.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2%2526Sect2=HITOFF%2526p=1%2526u=%25252Fnetahtml%25252FPTO%25252Fsearch-bool.html%2526r=1%2526f=G%2526l=50%2526co1=AND%2526d=PG01%2526s1=1234321%2526OS=1234321%2526RS=1234321&PageNum=&Rtype=&SectionNum=&idkey=EC70A3AD3AB3).

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What version(s) of: **Firefox**, **Ubuntu** ?  What URL, at USPO ?

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla has disabled the icetea-plugin for security reasons. As far as i see, there has be no updates right now to fix this problem. You could enable that plugin in the Firefox AddOn/Plugins menu. But that is *not* recommended and then youre at your own for potential risks. The security issues that are adressed by the decission are in the wild and even if linux may not be the first target for attackers its a big potential security risk.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin required for viewing USPTO full text database images is a TIFF plugin - Linux support is somewhat lacking but I have been able to view the images under 12.04 / Firefox 22 after installing the mozplugger package (from the universe repository)

```
sudo apt-get install mozplugger
```

and restarting the browser. The [mozplugger](http://mozplugger.mozdev.org/) package appears to be a binary distribution of [plugger](http://fredrik.hubbe.net/plugger.html) which wraps an ImageMagick component to handle the TIFF format, so you may need ImageMagick to be installed as well, although I believe that is usually in the default desktop installation.

The USPTO's own documentation is [here](http://www.uspto.gov/patft/help/images.htm) but it is somewhat out of date ('Netscape Communicator')